# Convention for showing time of post

Tags: messaging, convention

I'm working on page that has posts and comments to these posts. Each post/comment will say when it was posted relative to now.

My question is, is there any convention to doing this?

I'll explain:

Let's say the comment was posted 5 weeks ago.Should I use: "5 weeks ago"?
What if it was 8 weeks? Should i use "2 months ago" or "8 weeks ago"?.
What if it was 3 months ago? Do I just write "January 2014"?

Just looking if a convention exists before I make one up :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if you're using Rails as I am, it unsurprisingly has a built in method for this called `distance_of_time_in_words_from_now`